# Should I suppress CA2204: Literals should be spelled correctly?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-analysis, fxcop, conventions

I've recently upgraded my project from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010.

By enabling Code Analysis, I'm getting a lot of warnings resulted in rule CA2204: Literals should be spelled correctly.

**EDIT**:

Let's say I have a method called `GetResult()`, and in it I want to throw an exception for some reason. I want the exception to say `"GetResult() has failed for some reason"`. This will give me the warning since GetResult isn't a word. I won't get a warning on the method name `GetResult()`, only if I put it in a string. This is because Get and Result are legal words.

I don't believe that writing `GetResult() has failed for some reason` is the solution.

**EDIT**: In [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264488.aspx) it says:

> This rule parses the literal string
>   into words, **tokenizing compound words**,
>   and checks the spelling of each
>   word/token.

Doesn't that mean that GetResult should be checked as two words: "Get" and "Result"?

Should I suppress CA2204?

Comment: I don't understand your edit. You get a warning for GetResult, but you don't get a warning for GetResult? Please clarify.

Comment: I think you should review your edit, it doesn't make sense now.

Comment: I've made the edit more clear, the point is the GetResult() method is a good name for a method and I don't get a warning for it. But if I put that name in a string I do get a warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"Can't initialize MyClass"` is not a good message for a developer to introduce into code.  It rarely aids in debugging and it only confuses the end user if it's ever displayed.

In general, I would say don't suppress the message because spelling error makes one look much dumber than they really are and that's not a message you want to convey with your app.

In this *specific* instance, it's really a warning of a poor error message -- either tell the user how to correct it, correct it automatically, or include the actual reason it isn't initializing in your error log.

**EDIT:**  Including OP's edits
Something you can take from this warning is that you shouldn't be revealing code details as part of an error message (primarily because they will be included in the call stack when you log the exception).

`GetResult() has failed for some reason`
Let's say "some reason" is permissions.  The message could read:

> You don't have permission to view these results.

There's no need to mention the specific method that failed because the stack trace can be logged automatically.

Comment: ArgumentNullException and ArgumentException appear to be exceptions to this advice

Answer (score 4):

One way to fix this is to not add the type name into the string directly.  Instead pass it as a parameter.  For example

```
var msg = String.Format("Can't initialize {0}", typeof(MyClass).Name);
```

This has the benefit of both getting around the FxCop rule and being safe for refactoring.

Comment: Nice try. This also happens when I use method names... Look at my edit.

Comment: I think he'll need to explicitly provide IFormatProvider or FXCop will throw a Globalization warning. `String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Can't initialize {0}", typeof(MyClass).Name)` should do the trick.

Comment: In C# 6, you can use `nameof` for the same effect, except CodeAnalysis now sees the string literal and complains the type-name isn't a valid word. This is a warning that should be suppressed if it's talking about type names, imo.

Answer (score 2):

May be you should not put class name into literal? What about using or defining exception that can be thrown like this:

```
throw new CantInitializeClassException(innerException, typeof(MyClass);
```

My idea was to move more information to more specific exceptions from more general ones. I suggest using the sample above instead of `throw new ApplicationException("Cant initialize MyClass");`

Comment: Nice try. This also happens when I use method names... Look at my edit.

Comment: @brickner - same thing. method name is included into stack trace. should be at least if your stack chain is ok. this information should be described by exception object.

Comment: @Andrey, you're right. Do you think I should use MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name instead of writing the name? You might have a point but it seems like it just complicates the code...

Comment: @brickner - no. when you throw exception CLR writes method name into StackTrace field

Comment: @bricker: "into words" means sequences of characters separated by delimiters, i.e. space. MyClass is considered a word. Really i think this is stupid rule and discussion went to rhetorics. if you don't like it - suppress it and get back to work :)

Answer (score 1):

`CA2204` is all about spelling. Unfortunately even in VS2012 it still has an old annoying bug where it fails to tokenize compound words: http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/feedback/details/521030

This caused me to switch off this rule in our code analysis rule set.

Comment: It looks like this incorrect behaviour still isn't fixed in Visual Studio 2017. It has to be a bug because the documentation for CA2204 says it breaks-up compound words.